# Bootstrap 3 set image height automaticly to be div height

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have question about setting image height to became div height in bootstrap. I have four images to be like landing page, and every image need's to be set into container as background of div. Here is my code so if you can see where I'm wrong:

```
HTML

    <!--Start navi-->
    <navi>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top " role="navigation" style="border:none;">
        <div class="navbar-inner"> <!--changes made here-->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"
                            data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        <img src="../logo_header_smaller.png" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a class="btn btn-lg" href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </nav>
    <!--End navi-->

    <div class="container-fluid image1">
        <!--First Image-->  
        <div class="row image1">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 text-center" >
                <h1 style="color:white">Pojednostavnite svoje poslovanje</h1>
                <h4 style="color:white">Ponude, računi, vođenje zalihe, pregled poslovanja...</h4>
                <h4 style="color:white">sve na jednom mjestu!</h4>
                <br>
                <br>
                <button style="font-weight:600" class="btn btn-md round">ISPORBAJTE APLIKACIJU</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

CSS

    html,body{

      height:100%;
        font-family:  'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
      margin:0; 
      padding:0;
    }

    .navbar {
       background-color: transparent;
       background: transparent;
    }

    .container-fluid{
      width:100%;
    }

    .image1{
      background: url("..landing/homepage_image_hero.png") no-repeat center top scroll;
      background-size: 100% auto;
      height:100%;
      }
   .image2{
      background: url("../landing/homepage_image.png") no-repeat center top scroll;
      background-size: 100% auto;
      height:100%;
      }
```

Real image is size: 
img1 - width:1400px height:632px
img2 - widht:1400px height:632px

Better question is how to set widouth padding when I wanna insert text to div where image is in background. Thx for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `background-size:contain;`

w3schools link: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=contain

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi I'v try with that setting but wont do any changes. Image widouth padding-bottom:45% woth show it self.<div class="col-lg-12" style="background-image:url('../landing/homepage_image_hero.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:100% 650px;">

</div>

Comment: did you add a height to the div. set a min-height as 632px.

Comment: Yep i solved it with settings background-size:cover;